# Docker - cannot copy to non-directory: /var/lib/docker/overlay2/xw77p2bxfkhhnwqs5umpl7cbi/merged/app/.git

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am trying to build a docker image on my windows machine and I keep getting this error:

```
[+] Building 2.1s (12/15)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                       0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 538B                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 35B                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:alpine                                                                                                                                             1.0s 
 => [ 1/11] FROM docker.io/library/node:alpine@sha256:6b56197d33a56cd45d1d1214292b8851fa1b91b2ccc678cee7e5fd4260bd8fae                                                                                     0.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                          1.0s 
 => => transferring context: 15.72kB                                                                                                                                                                       1.0s 
 => CACHED [ 2/11] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s 
 => CACHED [ 3/11] COPY package.json .                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s 
 => CACHED [ 4/11] COPY tsconfig.json .                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s 
 => CACHED [ 5/11] COPY swagger.yaml .                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s 
 => CACHED [ 6/11] COPY services .                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s 
 => CACHED [ 7/11] RUN yarn install                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s 
 => ERROR [ 8/11] ADD . /app                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
------
 > [ 8/11] ADD . /app:
------
cannot copy to non-directory: /var/lib/docker/overlay2/xw77p2bxfkhhnwqs5umpl7cbi/merged/app/.git
```

My Dockerfile is the following:

```
FROM node:alpine

#Create Directory for the Container
WORKDIR /app

#Copy the package.json and tsconfig.json to work directory
COPY package.json .
COPY tsconfig.json .
COPY swagger.yaml .
COPY services . 

#Install all packages
RUN yarn install

#Copy all other source code to work directory
ADD . /app

#Build sources
RUN yarn run build

#Clean src directory
RUN rm -rf ./src/
RUN rm -rf ./services/src/

#Expose Ports
EXPOSE 3000

#Entry
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

This Dockerfile works on my colleagues' Linux machines but fails on my windows machine.

This is my Docker version

```
Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350
```

Running on windows and using the wsl 2 to interact with it.

But the build also fails using the Windows command prompt.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Are you using docker for windows ?

Comment: @abhishekphukan Yes, I am using Docker Desktop for windows

Comment: There is a WSL setting that needs to be enabled. Did you check if that is okay? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-containers

Comment: @abhishekphukan I also tried to build another project that used an identical Dockerfile and it worked. Docker and wsl were working well, just not for this one thing...

Comment: Did the other dockerfile also had a .git folder being copied ?

Comment: Also you may try replacing the ADD command with COPY command if you don’t have anything that needs to be extracted

Answer (score 5):

Just verify the .git is actually a file or folder. Or ***check for any name conflict between a folder and file***.

Seems like you are trying to copy a folder to a file(non-directory).

I have faced a similar issue `error: failed to solve: cannot replace to directory /var/lib/docker/overlay2/*/*/folder_a with file`. Turns out i have a binary file with a name 'folder_a'.

***Deleting the file which matches the folder_name solved the issue for me.***

Answer (score 1):

My case
Destination directory not created before copy command

```
RUN mkdir <destination directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced a similar issue, when trying to copy only the necessary files of my monorepo. This occurs when your are trying to copy files to a non-existent directory.

```
COPY package.json .

COPY ./packages/shared-ui/package.json packages/shared-ui
COPY ./packages/shared-ui packages/shared-ui

COPY ./apps/frontend/package.json apps/frontend
COPY ./apps/frontend apps/frontend
```

To fix this, you first need to create the `apps/frontend` directory & `packages/shared-ui` directory before copying over the source files.

```
COPY package.json .

/* Create these directories first */
RUN mkdir -p packages/shared-ui
RUN mkdir -p apps/frontend

COPY ./packages/shared-ui/package.json packages/shared-ui
COPY ./packages/shared-ui packages/shared-ui

COPY ./apps/frontend/package.json apps/frontend
COPY ./apps/frontend apps/frontend
```

The `-p` flag is important to include with `mkdir` else the command won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to dockerize the frontend project and I had to "COPY . ." in the Dockerfile. In my case this error was thrown while copying the node_modules directory into image. I created the ***.dockerignore*** file at the root project level. Then I added node_modules to it. Problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue with the COPY command and resolved it by adding the directory name in the destination path as suggested in https://sumito.jp/2021/08/04/cannot-copy-to-non-directory-var-lib-docker-overlay2/

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30114721)